# How do I determine reason for Selenium Grid hub unexpected shutdown

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I have a Selenium Grid with the following setup:

- Server (Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard ) with Grid hub
  (selenium-server-3.14.0).
- 12 x PCs with Selenium Nodes(selenium-server-3.14.0)
  (each with 4 max sessions/instances of Chrome).
- All these remote machines being managed with PowerShell scripts.

For some reason the Hub shuts down without warning. Sometimes this is during test execution, at other times when idle. It can stay running for days, other times a few hours. I can't find any obvious pattern relating to load or time.

I have tried to find the reason for the shut downs in Windows Event Viewer but can't find any notifications regarding the hub.

Is there any logging that can be set up on the Hub to help determine the reason for crashes?

This is specifically regarding behaviour of the Selenium Grid Hub. It has nothing to do with chromedriver or idle session behaviour. the question is not answered be those deemed to be duplicates.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is related to the behaviour of the Grid Hub. It has nothing to do with chromedriver or remote webdriver idle sessions.

Comment: Can you update the question with your _configuration_ / _commands_ / _code trials_ / _log messages_ to demonstrate how this question is different from the dup marked discussions?

Comment: Is there a way too prevent selenium automatically terminating idle sessions? is about how hub/nodes handle session timeouts and client crashes. This post is about the Hub server shutting down without warning. 

How to disable selenium chrome driver's auto closed action after some time without activity? is about chromedriver's handling of session timeouts. Again nothing to do with the Hub shutting down or crashing. I'm not interested in the client end. I just want to know how to track causes of server shutdowns. This question is completely unrelated to these questions.

Comment: You are yet to provide us any information in-terms of your _configuration_ / _commands_ / _code trials_ / _log messages_ to demonstrate how this question is different from the dup marked discussions. Update the question with all the  relevant information to `ReOpen` this discussion.

Comment: Have you actually read the post and my comments? Do you understand that they are about completely separate entities? I can't give a code example or log messages. I trying to get example of code or config that would allow my to access log messages.

Comment: Don't worry about it I asked the question again and have finally got a related response.

Comment: _Don't worry about it I asked the question again and have finally got a related response._ Nice to know that!!!